# Concept of Test-lists in Test Driven Development

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

In TDD, every body talks about creation of unit tests and how development is done. I know whole cycle but no body talks about the creation of these unit tests from requirements?
I have read somewhere in the literature that it is always good to create a test-list before developing these unit tests. My question is:
**What exactly the procedure (steps) being followed before writing unit tests in TDD? means that whether the Unit tests are written directly from the requirements without using any formal standard or test-lists are created before developing them?**

Comment: I would think that the requirements spec would influence functional tests more than unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test list only is a temporary repository for the next test cases. It is totally *informal*.

The main role of the test-list is here to free your mind. When you think about a new test, just write it down at the end of your list, then you can and forget it, and  focus on the problem at hand.

There is no procedure to write the tests and the list, it's just as when you create an UML model from the requirements. You think about the problem and produce a design. Once the design is complete, you start the implementation. With TDD, you think about the problem from a testing perspective, you write down some tests on the list and you start with the simpler test in the list. You can add (or remove) a test to the list at any time.

The [bowling game episode](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm) is a short read that illustrates the transition from requirements to unit tests. It does not mention any test-list though.

I maintain my test-list as comments at the bottom of my unit tests source file.

```
void test_foobarShallFailWithNull(void) {
...
}
// the tests I *may* write next
//void test_foobarShallFailWhenX(void)
//void test_foobarShallWorkWhenY(void)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, when doing TDD, the requirements are used to directly identify the required unit tests. In theory, the developer will choose one small aspect of the overall set of requirements and write a single unit test for that aspect, then write the simplest code to make that single test pass. In reality, the requirements and the aspects of those requirements chosen may lead the developer to identify several unit tests at once. Test lists are used as a parking lot so that the developer does not need to worry about losing test ideas while still being able to focus on one test at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too heavy or formal, you just sit down and jot down all the tests you can think of on a piece of paper (or a spreadsheet or a text file) before you start a task.

Then you work through the list picking them off one by one, crossing them out when they are done. If you come up with some new tests during implementation, you add it to the test list and continue to focus on the current test. When you have no more tests on your list, you are done.

The unit tests for TDD are fine-grained and in most cases, requirement/specs are not. So you use requirement documents to come up with system-level acceptance tests. And to make a specific acceptance test pass, you come up with a bunch of tasks that you implement using TDD.

Answer (score 0):

I use [equivalence partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) to generate a list of test cases.